# Korean MUI Language Pack installed in Windows 7 Ultimate, but Korean language still not supported?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, language-pack, korean

When that large batch of updates came by and asked me if I wanted to install all of the auxiliary languages, I selected yes to all of them, waited a few hours, and installed every language available through Windows Update.

I can create and save a file's contents and it's name using arabic text, chinese text, japanese text, etc, but not with korean text. It only shows a bunch of squares in place of each letter.

Basically the korean language pack I installed simply doesn't work. I can see korean text showing through firefox if I visit a korean webpage, but the title of the page is always rectangles, and any text I cope from the page (into a program or into a filename) comes out as rectangles.

Has anybody come across a similar problem?

The only suggestion I have read a few times is basically "switch your Windows to use a Korean system by default", which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing (through control panel Regional/Language settings) the Korean language and re-installing from windows update (with a non-required re-start) seemed to fix the problem.